# templates, insufficient type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm playing with an implementation of Streams à la Java 8. I'd prefer the compiler to accept the following piece of code

```
Stream stream;
stream
    .map      ([] (int x)  { return 10*x; })      // error
    .forEach  ([] (int x)  { cout << x << " ";});
```

but the compiler (gcc version 4.9.2) refuses it, with the note

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
‘main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<Re(int)>’
   .map       ([] (int x)  { return 10*x; })
requires a type parameter for `map`
```

It compiles (and runs well) with

```
   .map<int>  ([] (int x)  { return 10*x; })
```

Is there any hope to get rid of the `<map>` thingy ?

---

Here is the reduced code (with sufficient declarations)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename Tfrom, typename Tto> class MappedStream;

template <typename T>
class Stream
{
  public:
    void forEach(function< void(T) > action) 
    {}

    template <typename Re>
    MappedStream<T,Re> map (function < Re(T)> mapping) {
        return MappedStream<T,Re>(*this, mapping);
    }
};

template <typename Tfrom, typename Tto>
class MappedStream
   : public Stream<Tto>
{   
  public:
    MappedStream(Stream<Tfrom> & source,
                function <Tto(Tfrom)> mapping)
    {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
  Stream<int> stream;
  stream
   .map<int> ([] (int x) { return 10*x; })
   //  XXXXX                          <- how to get rid of this?
   .forEach  ([] (int x) { cout << x << " ";});

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could do [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dfd82ff3c7d075b), but I guess it breaks your design (you seem to like `std::function`s)

Comment: You cannot deduce `std::function` from lambda.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda is not a `std::function`, and you almost *never* want to use `std::function</* something that contains a template parameter */>` as a function template's parameter, because the only way the template parameter in there can be deduced is if the caller constructs a `std::function` and passes it in.

Instead, accept any function object, and then figure out the return type:

```
template <typename F, typename Re = std::result_of_t<F&(T)>>
MappedStream<T,Re> map (F mapping) {
    return MappedStream<T,Re>(*this, mapping);
}
```

In general, unnecessary type erasure should be avoided. It's arguably useful for a `MappedStream`'s type to not depend on the mapper used, so storing a `std::function` inside is reasonable, but `forEach` probably should be a template accepting any function object, rather than just a `std::function`.